# OSB proxy retrieving contents from AWS S3 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, osb

I've a created a proxy service in Oracle Service Bus OSB (11.1.1.7)/Weblogic(10.3.6). The proxy service need to fetch contents from AWS S3 and has a Java callout to invoke java class which fetches contents from S3. The java class is packaged in a jar file (mylib.jar). I exported the proxy, the jar file (mylib.jar) and dependent libraries (aws sdk for s3 and dependent libraries) from OEPE(eclipse modeler) in a config jar (myconfig.jar). When I try to deploy myconfig.jar in OSB using sbconsole, it gives error - (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream) while importing it. The class S3ObjectInputStream is part of the aws sdk (aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.34.jar) and is included in the deployable - myconfig.jar file. Alternatively, I tried including the jar files in the classpath of the OSB server and removing it from the myconfig.jar but it didn't help either. Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the dependent jar files in the OSB AdminServer's classpath fixed the issue. Deployment goes through without errors.